# SQL JOIN statement not outputting correct data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am having an issue with either my SQL makeup or my query. I am building a comment system and I have two databases. I am attempting to `JOIN` the databases and have the query work properly.

What I am attempting to do is get the img from `profile_img` that is associated with the user_id from both tables. However, I only want the last image from the user (within the profile_img database) to show. When I upload profile images, they simply add on and I only output the last one uploaded.

The databases I am using are:

**home_comments:**

```
id, user_id, username, comment, date
```

**profile_img structure:**

```
id, user_id, img
```

My original `SQL` was this

```
$select_comments_sql = "
    SELECT c. *,
    p.user_id, p.img
    FROM home_comments AS c
    INNER JOIN profile_img AS p
    WHERE c.user_id = p.user_id
    ORDER BY id DESC
";
```

This original `SELECT` `SQL` works with my query, which is:

```
if ($select_comments_stmt = $con->prepare($select_comments_sql)) {
        //$select_comments_stmt->bind_param("s", $user_id);
        $select_comments_stmt->execute();
        if (!$select_comments_stmt->errno) {
            //echo "error";
        }
        $select_comments_stmt->bind_result($comment_id, $comment_user_id, $comment_username, $home_comments, $comment_date, $commenter_user_id, $commenter_img);
    //var_dump($select_comments_stmt);  
        $comment_array = array();
        while ($select_comments_stmt->fetch()) {
            $comment_array[] = $comment_user_id;
            $comment_array[] = $comment_username;
            $comment_array[] = $home_comments;
            $comment_array[] = $comment_date;
            $comment_array[] = $commenter_user_id;
            $comment_array[] = $commenter_img;
            $commenter_img = '<img class="home-comment-profile-pic" src=" '.$commenter_img.'">';
            if ($home_comments === NULL) {
                echo 'No comments found.';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="comment-post-box">';
                echo $commenter_img;
                echo '<div class="comment-post-username">'.$comment_username. '</div>';
                echo '<div class="comment-post-text">'.$home_comments. '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
  }
```

This produces the user's profile picture for their comment, however, it makes duplicate comments for each profile image the user has.

I now, have this new `SQL` to try and resolve this issue (which it shows it works in an SQL fiddle), but it outputs nothing:

```
$select_comments_sql = "
    SELECT c. *, p.user_id, p.img
    FROM home_comments AS c
    INNER JOIN (SELECT max(id) as id, user_id 
                FROM profile_img 
                GROUP BY user_id) PI
      on PI.user_id = C.user_id
    INNER JOIN profile_img p
      on PI.user_id = p.user_id
     and PI.id = P.id
    ORDER BY C.id DESC
";
```

So, is there something wrong with my prepared statement/output or is the new `SQL SELECT` statement not correct?

Does anyone see what is wrong with this? Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: `AS c` and you're using `C.` - that could be case-sensitive, TBH I don't know that for certain, same for the `p`'s. Check for errors on the query with mysqli_error() and it will tell you.

Comment: The case sensativity did it! Thanks! Feel free to leave an answer. Quick question though - based on the way my query is laid out, how could I add error reporting to it? I am trying to write with PDO, so not sure how to do it with this.

Comment: Use PDO's built-in error checking  `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', USER, PASS); 
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` for example

Comment: @Becky You're welcome Becky, glad to have been of help, *cheers*

Comment: @JayBlanchard It looks as if Fred was suggesting try/catch, is there any significance over using your methods than what he recommended?

Comment: I use those methods with try/catch but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to a comment I left:

> *"The case sensativity did it! Thanks! Feel free to leave an answer. Quick question though - based on the way my query is laid out, how could I add error reporting to it? I am trying to write with PDO, so not sure how to do it with this. – Becky"*

As it appears, aliases are case-sensitive, therefore you need to change your query to:

```
$select_comments_sql = "
        SELECT c. *, p.user_id, p.img
        FROM home_comments AS c
        INNER JOIN (SELECT max(id) as id, user_id 
                    FROM profile_img 
                    GROUP BY user_id) PI
          on PI.user_id = c.user_id
        INNER JOIN profile_img p
          on PI.user_id = p.user_id
         and PI.id = p.id
        ORDER BY c.id DESC
    ";
```

- By default, table aliases are case sensitive on Unix, but not so on Windows or OS

Using exceptions/error handling on the query would have signaled an error.

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Thanks again for the help.